# First test case always failing in selenium webdriver test suite run

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

In Nunit test suite run in Continuous integration, Every time first test case is failing with the following error:

```
SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/384a1a60-4ed3-4cac-8143-265aa63ec980/url timed out after 60 seconds.
 ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]]>
```

The server has Windows8 server and Mozilla firefox v 21

Code is :

```
#region TestSetup
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    browser = ConfigurationHelper.GetWebDriver();
    browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationHelper.GetConsumerBankingURL());
    browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    loginPage = new LoginPage(browser);
    user = VoyagerHelper.EnrollUser();
    //The user should be able to successfully logged into the system. The default destination page shows up
    financialOverviewPage = loginPage.Login(user.UserName, ConfigurationBase.DefaultPassword) as FinancialOverviewPage;
    accountNumbers = financialOverviewPage.GetAccountNumber();
}
#endregion

#region TestTearDown

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    try
    {
        financialOverviewPage.Logout();
    }
    finally
    {
        browser.Quit();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: No where near enough information to go on. Post the *full* stack trace, and a copy of your `TearDown` code. Something is `null` in there, we have **no idea at all** what it is because you've not shown us *anything*.

Comment: please attach the code u've tried to run. make sure that all the variables declared have been properly initialized.

Comment: <![CDATA[SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/384a1a60-4ed3-4cac-8143-265aa63ec980/url timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: This could be anything. What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Set up region is throwing error SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/384a1a60-4ed3-4cac-8143-265aa63ec980/url timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: What **line** is throwing this error? I am not asking *what* the error is, you've told us, I'm asking, *what line* is throwing the error.